# Facebook LoginButton got IOException

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I got the following error when clicking on the com.facebook.widget.LoginButton:

```
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$AuthorizationRequest)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6660)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.resolveIntent(IPackageManager.java:1904)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivityAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:459)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivity(ApplicationPackageManager.java:453)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.facebook.Session.resolveIntent(Session.java:1067)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.facebook.Session.tryLoginActivity(Session.java:1053)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.facebook.Session.authorize(Session.java:890)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:957)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Session.java:385)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:641)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mypackage.myapp.LoginActivity
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
06-04 09:47:47.142: E/AndroidRuntime(30567):    ... 25 more
```

I followed this tutorial by facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/
But instead of using fragments I used an Activity. Could this have something to do with it?

The error says it is trying to serialize my Activity which is weird... When implementing Serializable in the Activity it gives an error saying the LoginButton is not serializable. When implementing it in the LoginButton it gives the same error on another class, and so on and so on.

My Activity (I also pass the other lifecycle  :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        call(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    fbClient.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.fbClient = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, this);
    this.fbClient.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    this.btFacebook = (LoginButton)this.findViewById(R.id.login_facebook);
    this.btFacebook.setReadPermissions(new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("user_likes"); }});
}

@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    Log.i("LoginActivity", "call()");

    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("LoginActivity", "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("LoginActivity", "Logged out...");
    }
}
```